# Difference between keep away and keep away from

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, phrase-usage, sentence-structure, phrasal-verbs

**1. He keeps away smoking.
2. He keeps away from smoking.**

This is a question given in option to choose only one sentence as correct sentence. It seems that both sentences are correct but in different contexts. Yet it's difficult to stick to one sentence as correct and other as incorrect. So if we are to choose one correct sentence out of these two above mentioned sentences, which one would be that?

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct with different meanings.  But the meaning of one sentence is a typical thing one might say, and the other is rather odd.

"He keeps away from smoking" is a normal enough sentence.  It means "He doesn't smoke. He avoids it."

"He keeps away smoking" without a comma could mean "he prevents smoking from coming near.  I imagine a parent has paid a bodyguard to ensure that no smokers come near her child.  That would be rather odd.

"He keeps away, smoking" (I've inserted a comma to help the sense) would mean that he avoids (something, perhaps he avoids the speaker) and he smokes as he does so.  That is also rather odd.

So there is only one possible answer, there is only one sentence that could express an idea that you might have.